# Identification of flowering houseplant

Tags: identification, houseplants, indoors, flowering

It resembles an *Aloe* or *Agave* maybe a *Pandanus*, I am not sure. The leaves are spiky. The flower seems to be on its way out, but more or less it looked the same before I took the pictures. Long stalk, with red bloom.

The plant is not mine, I took the pictures in the stairway of a flat. They kept the plant on the window sill all winter, an unheated area.

| [image] | [image] |
| --- | --- |
| [image: flower of the plant] | [image] |

Comment: Appears to be a Bromeliad, hopefully the flower will help to ID further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a friendship plant (*Billbergia nutans*), which is indeed from the Bromeliaceae (Bromeliad) family. [Here](http://www.flowersinisrael.com/exoticBillbergianutans_page.htm) are some pictures of the flowers, they originate from South America.

It is an easy houseplant (very resistant to neglect), and is easily propagated by splitting. [Here](https://www.houseplantsexpert.com/queens-tears-plant.html) are some more details about the plant.